# How to parse with parse5?

Tags: node.js

As example parse5. Parse function return document. But, querySelector function doesn't exist. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { parse } from 'parse5';

(async () => {
    const options = {
        redirect: "manual"
    };

    const response = await fetch('https://google.com', options);

    const dom = parse(await response.text());

    console.log(dom.querySelector('title'));
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The object that the parse function returns is called a Document, but it's not the same as the Web API Document you'd find in a browser. Instead, it's the root of a very simple tree data structure. The documentation for this data structure is at https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/blob/master/packages/parse5/docs/tree-adapter/default/interface-list.md

Despite its simplicity, the tree has everything you need to parse the document. It's likely that you'll have to recursively search for the element you're looking for. Try this code as an example:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { parse } = require('parse5');

const getDescendantByTag = (node, tag) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes?.length; i++) {
    if (node.childNodes[i].tagName === tag) return node.childNodes[i];

    const result = getDescendantByTag(node.childNodes[i], tag);
    if (result) return result;
  }

  return null;
};

fetch('https://google.com', { redirect: 'manual' })
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    console.log(getDescendantByTag(parse(text), 'title'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think Node.JS has no implementation for querySelector.

You can use polyfill to solve this, like [this implementation at Github](https://github.com/cobbdb/polyfill-queryselector)

```js
/**
 * Polyfills the querySelector and querySelectorAll methods.
 * @see https://gist.github.com/Fusselwurm/4673695
 */
(function () {
    var style;
    var select = function (selector, maxCount) {
        var all = document.all,
            l = all.length,
            i,
            resultSet = [];

        style.addRule(selector, "foo:bar");
        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            if (all[i].currentStyle.foo === "bar") {
                resultSet.push(all[i]);
                if (resultSet.length > maxCount) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        style.removeRule(0);
        return resultSet;
    };
    if (document.querySelectorAll || document.querySelector) {
        return;
    }
    style = document.createStyleSheet();

    document.querySelectorAll = document.body.querySelectorAll = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, Infinity);
    };
    document.querySelector = document.body.querySelector = function (selector) {
        return select(selector, 1)[0] || null;
    };
}());
```

Polyfills help with browser support and implementations for NodeJS. You can use same technique for other functions (in example, to support non-existent functions in IE7 in a React application).

> NOTE: Also available as npm package, [see https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-queryselector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-queryselector)

Comment: can u see carefully again the question? i asking parse html with parse5 library.

Comment: Yes, i've read it. Parse5 library [returns an Document](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5/blob/master/packages/parse5/docs/index.md#parse). Document objects have no native implementation for querySelector in NodeJS, you can either use alternative methods or polyfill the querySelector for Document object, which refers to this answer. I'm not telling you to use another lib, just answered how you can use querySelector with parse5, and that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[hast-util-select](http://unifiedjs.com/explore/package/hast-util-select/) can help

```js
/*
npm i parse5 hast-util-from-parse5 hast-util-to-html hast-util-select
*/

import {parse} from 'parse5'
import {fromParse5} from 'hast-util-from-parse5'
import {toHtml} from 'hast-util-to-html'
import {matches, select, selectAll} from 'hast-util-select'

function parseHtml(source) {
  const p5ast = parse(source, { sourceCodeLocationInfo: true })
  return fromParse5(p5ast)
}

const html = `
  <html>
    <body>
      <div class="some-class">find me 1</div>
      <div class="some-class">find me 2</div>
      <div>ignore me</div>
    </body>
  </html>
`

const tree = parseHtml(html)

for (const div of selectAll("div.some-class", tree)) {
  //console.dir(div)
  console.log(toHtml(div))
}
```

gives

```
<div class="some-class">find me 1</div>
<div class="some-class">find me 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine we need to get all the texts of `<code>` element from the HTML structure like that:

```html
    <article class="main-page-content">
      ..
      <section class="section-content">
        ..
        <dt id="docmument.something">
          ..
          <code>Text</code>
        </dt>
      </section>
    </article>
```

The code may look like that:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { parse, serialize } from 'parse5';

const getDescendantsByTag = (node, tag) => {
  const descendants = [];
  const nodes = [node];
  while (nodes.length) {
    const currentNode = nodes.pop();
    if (currentNode.tagName === tag) {
      descendants.push(currentNode);
    }
    if (currentNode.childNodes) {
      nodes.push(...currentNode.childNodes);
    }
  }
  return descendants;
};

fetch('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    const document = parse(text);
    const article = getDescendantsByTag(document, 'article')
      .find((node) => node.attrs.some((attr) => attr.name === 'class' && attr.value === 'main-page-content'));

    const sectionContents = getDescendantsByTag(article, 'div')
      .filter((node) => node.attrs.some((attr) => attr.name === 'class' && attr.value === 'section-content'));

    const codeTexts = sectionContents.flatMap((section) => {
      const dts = getDescendantsByTag(section, 'dt')
        .filter((node) => node.attrs.some((attr) => attr.name === 'id' && attr.value.startsWith('document.')));

      return dts.flatMap((dt) => {
        const codeNodes = getDescendantsByTag(dt, 'code');
        return codeNodes.map((codeNode) => serialize(codeNode).replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').trim());
      });
    });

    console.log(codeTexts.reverse());
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Or if you decide to use HAST(HTML Abstract Syntax Tree) util:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { parse } from 'parse5';
import { fromParse5 } from 'hast-util-from-parse5'
import { select, selectAll } from 'hast-util-select';

fetch('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    const document = parse(text);
    const hast = fromParse5(document);
    const article = select('article.main-page-content', hast);
    const sectionContents = selectAll('div.section-content', article);

    const codeTexts = sectionContents.flatMap((section) => {
      const dts = selectAll('dt[id^="document."]', section);

      return dts.flatMap((dt) => {
        const codeNodes = selectAll('code', dt);
        return codeNodes.map((codeNode) => codeNode.children[0].value.trim());
      });
    });
    console.log(codeTexts);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```